# How can I run my process of insert into database in background when my app is runing?

Tags: android, background

How can I run my process of insert into database in background when my application is running? I want to run the process of insert query of the database in background.

Please can you give suggestion or a sample code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the thread which will do the job of populating the database in background as your application is working normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a class that extends AsynTask...
Please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that.

Inside ur doInBackground() call ur method for doing insertion.

**More Explanation:**

Create an inner class InsertTask inside ur activity like:

```
private class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            Boolean success = false;

            try {
                //place insert code here
                success = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if(e.getMessage()!=null)
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return success;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            super.onPostExecute(success);
        }
    }
```

Inside ur onCreate() give:

```
new InsertTask.execute();  //this calls the doInBackground method of InsertTask
```

By doing this, when ur activity is called, the things written inside doInBackground() runs, there by inserting ur values.